# Find all possible rectangles based on point in 2D Grid

Tags: algorithm, lua, multidimensional-array, lua-table

I got the following map

```
local Map = {
    [1] = {
        [1] = 'Sand',
        [2] = 'Sand',
        [3] = 'Sand'
    },
    [2] = {
        [1] = 'Sand',
        [2] = 'Sand',
        [3] = 'Grass'
    },
    [3] = {
        [1] = 'Rock',
        [2] = 'Rock',
        [3] = 'Grass'
    },
}
```

The map above:

```
S = Sand
G = Grass
R = Rock
```

```
S S R
S S R
S G G
```

and try to make a function which I supply a point and it returns me an array of all possible rectangles with that type.

Something like

```
function GetRectangles(X, Y)
local Type = Map[X][Y]
local Result = {}
-- Get all rectangles with same type and add to array
return Result
end
```

So, when I call GetRectangles(1, 1), it returns me an array with the following rectangles

- Rectangle starting at 1, 1 and ending at 2, 2
- Rectangle tarting at 1, 1 and ending at 1, 3

And when I call GetRectangles(3, 3), it returns me an array with the following content

- Rectangle starting at 3, 3 and ending at 2, 3

How would I do this?

Comment: Provide an example with input and expected output.

Comment: What do you mean by "rectangle"?

Comment: How would you represent a rectangle with code?

Comment: @YuHao Something like {Position = {1, 1}, Size = {2, 3}} where 'Position' is the upper left-hand corner.

Comment: `Map[1][3]` is `S` not `R`. You won't get "_Rectangle starting at 1, 3 and ending at 2, 3_" for `GetRectangles(1, 3)`

Comment: You seem to be omitting rectangles that are contained in other rectangles. E.g. any `1x2` Sand rectangle. Is that the intent? Also, the point you select, must it be in the rectangles returned? Must it be the top left point in each rectangle?

Comment: @hjpotter92 I messed a lot of stuff up, for some reason. *Should* be fixed now.

Comment: @Rob No, rectangles aren't allowed to overlap each other (question should be fixed) and no, it should just be contained within that rectangle.

Comment: Also, what if your 2x2 grid is "S,R,R,S", i.e. S in top left and bottom right corner. What rectangles should be returned by `GetRectangles(1,1)`?

Comment: @Rob No, rectangles aren't allowed to overlap at all. In your case, it should only return the S. As any other case would mean that rectangles overlap.

Comment: @Jan: Any two rectangles that include point (1,1) overlap by definition. Your in the question example gives two rectangles that overlap on 2 points.

Comment: @Rob Oh damn, I'm sorry. Turns out I wasn't thinking when I replied. - Yes, returned rectangles are able to overlap (not possible otherwise, as each of them contains the starting point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider Backtracking.

```
recursive step:
    for each step in possible steps:
        check new rectangle for single type
            if ok, add to rectangle list and recurse
```

where possible steps are : add 1 column to the left, add 1 column to the right, add 1 row to above, add 1 row below.

example:

```
current rectangle (1,1), (1,1)
   rectangle is ok
   add 1 row below:
   current rectangle (1,1), (1,2)
       rectangle is ok, add
       add 1 row below
            current rectangle (1,1) (1,3)
            rectangle ok, add
            // add 1 row below not possible step
            add 1 column left  
            rectangle (1,1) (2,3) not ok
            no more steps    
       add 1 column left
       rectangle (1,1) (2,1) not ok
       no more steps
   etc...
```

for overlaps, iterate over list and remove them or hint: this can be done during iteration.